# When should I use Throwable.getSuppressed() and addSuppressed() in my code?

Tags: java, try-with-resources, try-finally

I'm practicing with try-with-resources for my methods to understand that.
This is my example method.

```
public void a(File f) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f)) { // suppose FileNotFoundException occurs here
        byte[] buffer = new byte[7];
        fis.read(buffer); // suppose IOException occurs here
    }
}
```

Now suppose that an exception occurs as `FileNotFoundException` for the new FileInputStream() and a `IOException` on the fis.read().

this is the use of my method in another class.

```
try {
            a(new File(""));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

            Throwable[] suppressedExceptions = ex.getSuppressed();
            if (suppressedExceptions.length > 0)
                for (Throwable exception : suppressedExceptions)
                    System.err.println(exception.toString());
        }
```

As in the previous code. Should I use the `getSuppressed()` method always when I use try-with-resources?
And when, where and how should I use `addSuppressed()` method?

Comment: What do you mean by "and a `IOException` on the `fis.read()`? You are not getting two exceptions, only one (the `FileNotFoundException`).

Comment: So, that's not possible to get an exception in the FileInputStream.read() method?

Comment: The `FileInputStream.read()` method can throw an exception, as indicated in the javadoc. However, when you get an exception earlier (like in the `new FileInputStream()` constructor) you have to deal with that exception first/instead.

Comment: I understand that now. Thanks. So, I don't need the addition of code that gets the suppressed exceptions every time I use the try-with-resources?